# Java: Problems with "this" keyword

Tags: java, package, this, non-static

I am trying to make a Java package 'mylib' with classes Library{} and Book{}.

Here is the code for class Library{}:

```
/*
 Create collection of books
 List books and status
 User input:
   'B' - Borrow a book
   'R' - Reserve a book
   'I' - Return a book
   'X' - Exit program
*/

package mylib;

public class Library {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Book[] MyBooks = new Book[3];
        Book x;

        MyBooks[0] = new Book("The Lover's Dictionary", "Levithan, D.", 211);
        MyBooks[1] = new Book("White Tiger", "Adiga, A.", 304);
        MyBooks[2] = new Book("Thirteen R3asons Why", "Asher, J.", 336);

        for (int i = 0; i < MyBooks.length; i++) {
            x = MyBooks[i];
            System.out.println((i + 1) + " " + x.sTitle);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code for class Book{}:

```
package mylib;

class Book {
    // Declare fields
    byte iStatus;
    int iPages;
    String sTitle, sAuthor;
    String sBorrowedBy, sReservedBy;
    String sDueDate, sReturnDate;

    public static final byte BORROWED = 0, AVAILABLE = 1, RESERVED = 2;

    // Constructor
    public Book(String Title, String Author, int Pages) {
        this.sTitle = Title;
        this.sAuthor = Author;
        this.iPages = Pages;
        this.iStatus = this.AVAILABLE;
    }

    // Borrow method
    static void borrowBook(String Borrower, String Due) {
        if (this.iStatus == this.AVAILABLE) {
            this.sBorrowedBy = Borrower;
            this.sDueDate = Due;
            this.iStatus = this.BORROWED;
        } else if (this.iStatus == this.RESERVED
                && this.sReservedBy == Borrower) {
            this.sBorrowedBy = Borrower;
            this.sDueDate = Due;
            this.sReservedBy = "";
            this.iStatus = this.BORROWED;
        }
    }

    /*
     * static int reserveBook(String Borrower) {
     * 
     * }
     * 
     * static void returnBook(String Return) {
     * 
     * }
     */
}
```

The partial codes above are given by the professor. I commented out the empty methods and tested the program just to see if it would compile.

I am having 14 errors with the this keyword. Any help?

Comment: Please don't start variable names with a capital letter. Refer to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367

Comment: The variables are from the prof, I will change that soonest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using this in a static context it is giving you the error. Try the following code:

```
package myLib;

class Book {
// Declare fields
byte iStatus;
int iPages;
String sTitle, sAuthor;
String sBorrowedBy, sReservedBy;
String sDueDate, sReturnDate;

public static final byte BORROWED = 0, AVAILABLE = 1, RESERVED = 2;

// Constructor
public Book(String Title, String Author, int Pages) {
    this.sTitle = Title;
    this.sAuthor = Author;
    this.iPages = Pages;
    this.iStatus = Book.AVAILABLE;
}

// Borrow method
//Remove the static keyword
//Refer to the remaining static variables like AVAILABLE OR BORROWED using Book and not this keyword.
 void borrowBook(String Borrower, String Due) {
    if(this.iStatus == Book.AVAILABLE) {
        this.sBorrowedBy = Borrower;
        this.sDueDate = Due;
        this.iStatus = Book.BORROWED;
    }
    else if(this.iStatus == Book.RESERVED && this.sReservedBy == Borrower) {
        this.sBorrowedBy = Borrower;
        this.sDueDate = Due;
        this.sReservedBy = "";
        this.iStatus = Book.BORROWED;
    }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the program compiled. Why must I use Book instead of this?

Comment: In your program the variables AVAILABLE , RESERVED and BORROWED are static in nature. The variables can be directly referred by using the name of the class. They are associated with the class and not object of the class. Moreover they are final in nature. Meaning they cannot be changed by the object of the class and there is only one copy of the variable available to all the objects. Hence use "Book" instead of "this". Please refer to the link posted by @Suresh Atta for understanding further.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `this` in static context , like `static` methods. Why are you making your `borrowBook()` method as `static`. It should be an instance method without the `static` keyword.

`static` methods belong to the class and is shared by all its instances. You can invoke them directly using the *classname* like `Book.borrowBook(....)` , if this happens the run time will have no idea what/which object `this` refers to in that context .

Read [JLS.3 15.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.3)

> The keyword this may be used only in the body of an instance method, instance initializer, or constructor, or in the initializer of an instance variable of a class. If it appears anywhere else, a compile-time error occurs.

---

In your case better to make the `borrowBook()` method an instance method as it changes the state of the invoking object i.e. modifies its attributes.Just change the method declaration and remove `static`:

```
void borrowBook(String Borrower, String Due) {....... }
```

Answer (score 2):

in this method

```
static void borrowBook(String Borrower, String Due) {
```

You cannot use `this`  in a `static`  context

As I see ,there is no need of making that method `static`.

Prefer to read [Understanding Instance and Class Members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use IDE to coding since this issue will understand by your own. because error is here use `this` in a `static` block.

Comment: +1 for suggesting IDE :).Missed that point.

Answer (score 0):

**this** keyword is used to refer non-static variables from non-static methods. You are referring to non-static variables from static method.

Answer (score 0):

just change this line :

```
static void borrowBook(String Borrower, String Due) {
```

to

```
public void borrowBook(String Borrower, String Due) {
```

Comment: Should I also make it into public class?